# Codename One: Place ImageButton, chage size, background color and of a Button and of a Form and responsive design

Tags: responsive-design, codenameone

I try my 4-large-imageButtons to place centred in my main form, so that these buttons for all devices (Smartphone and iPad) centrally placed in a beautiful shape in the main form.

My questions:

1 - How can I change the background color, size and position of a button?

2 - How can I (seeing) large image buttons (centered in the Main Form 2 top and 2 bottom) place in the main Form. Until now two bottom buttons slightly move down. they are not exactly centered in my opinion.

3 - How do I change the background color of the main form? What do I do if I want to use an image instead of a color?

4 - What should I do, that 4-large-ImageButtons look for smartphones smaller and for iPad large? Until now, these see full postponed for Smarphone screen. These do not fit exactly in Smarphone screen.

Here are some screenshots of what I have so far:
[image]

As can be seen, the buttons are not exactly centered and shown very large. All 4-buttons do not fit exactly in Smarphonescreen. Only one Button is to see. For the 3 others you have to scroll.
[image]

I set the MainForm so.
[image]

The placement of buttons should look like this for tablets and for Smartphones should be smaller.

Button 1, 2, 3 and 4 each have a transparent image. The transparent images come on that colors.
[image]

On the smartphone it should look for portrait format so:

[image]

But if i turn the Smartphone, for Landscape format it should look like (responsive design):

[image]

How can I best proceed. Could someone please explain step by step? That would be really great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `UIID` value to something other than Button e.g. Container or even MyButton so the push button background won't be there. Place the 4 buttons in a 2x2 grid layout. You can nest containers in various ways to achieve the layout you want see http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---positioning-components-using-layout-managers.html

Make sure the images for the buttons are MultiImages so they adapt to the various resolutions.